# How to read Crystal Report .rpt file using Python?

Tags: python, encoding, crystal-reports

For now, I am trying just to read the file and convert it into csv file. But I always get either `UnicodeDecodeError` or `UnicodeEncodeError`, no matter what encoding I try.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import codecs

with open("holder.csv", "w") as my_empty_csv:
    pass


def convert(inputFile, outputFile):
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
    fieldIndexes = []
    headers = ""

    for idx, val in enumerate(inputFile):
        if (idx == 0):
            headers = val
        elif (idx == 1):
            fieldIndexes = list(getFieldIndexes(val, " "))
            row = list(getFields(headers, fieldIndexes))
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            row = list(getFields(val, fieldIndexes))
            writer.writerow(row)


def getFieldIndexes(input, sep):
    lastIndex = 0
    for idx, c in enumerate(input):
        if (c == sep):
            yield (lastIndex, idx)
            lastIndex = idx + 1
    yield lastIndex, len(input)


def getFields(input, indexes):
    for index in indexes:
        yield input[index[0]:index[1]].strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) == 3):
        encodings = ['ascii',
                     'big5',
                     'big5hkscs',
                     'cp037',
                     'cp273',
                     'cp424',
                     'cp437',
                     'cp500',
                     'cp720',
                     'cp737',
                     'cp775',
                     'cp850',
                     'cp852',
                     'cp855',
                     'cp856',
                     'cp857',
                     'cp858',
                     'cp860',
                     'cp861',
                     'cp862',
                     'cp863',
                     'cp864',
                     'cp865',
                     'cp866',
                     'cp869',
                     'cp874',
                     'cp875',
                     'cp932',
                     'cp949',
                     'cp950',
                     'cp1006',
                     'cp1026',
                     'cp1125',
                     'cp1140',
                     'cp1250',
                     'cp1251',
                     'cp1252',
                     'cp1253',
                     'cp1254',
                     'cp1255',
                     'cp1256',
                     'cp1257',
                     'cp1258',
                     'euc_jp',
                     'euc_jis_2004',
                     'euc_jisx0213',
                     'euc_kr',
                     'gb2312',
                     'gbk',
                     'gb18030',
                     'hz',
                     'iso2022_jp',
                     'iso2022_jp_1',
                     'iso2022_jp_2',
                     'iso2022_jp_2004',
                     'iso2022_jp_3',
                     'iso2022_jp_ext',
                     'iso2022_kr',
                     'latin_1',
                     'iso8859_2',
                     'iso8859_3',
                     'iso8859_4',
                     'iso8859_5',
                     'iso8859_6',
                     'iso8859_7',
                     'iso8859_8',
                     'iso8859_9',
                     'iso8859_10',
                     'iso8859_11',
                     'iso8859_13',
                     'iso8859_14',
                     'iso8859_15',
                     'iso8859_16',
                     'johab',
                     'koi8_r',
                     'koi8_t',
                     'koi8_u',
                     'kz1048',
                     'mac_cyrillic',
                     'mac_greek',
                     'mac_iceland',
                     'mac_latin2',
                     'mac_roman',
                     'mac_turkish',
                     'ptcp154',
                     'shift_jis',
                     'shift_jis_2004',
                     'shift_jisx0213',
                     'utf_32',
                     'utf_32_be',
                     'utf_32_le',
                     'utf_16',
                     'utf_16_be',
                     'utf_16_le',
                     'utf_7',
                     'utf_8',
                     'utf_8_sig']
        for encoding in encodings:

            with open(sys.argv[1], encoding=encoding) as inputFile:
                with open(f"{sys.argv[2]}-{encoding}.csv", 'w', newline='') as outputFile:
                    try:
                        convert(inputFile, outputFile)
                        print(f"RIGHT ONE {encoding}")
                    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                        outputFile.close()
                        os.remove(
                            f"{sys.argv[2]}-{encoding}.csv")
                        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                        print(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                        print(f"Not {encoding}")
                    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
                        outputFile.close()
                        os.remove(
                            f"{sys.argv[2]}-{encoding}.csv")
                        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                        print(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                        print(f"Not {encoding}")

    else:
        print("Usage: rpt2csv.py inputFile outputFile")
```

I tried to iterate through any possible encodings that python supports, no luck, unfortunately. Is there a way to do this with python or maybe some other language if it's possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please augment your question with all the required code, as well as a sample of the input file's contents? What's missing are `getFields` as well as what you're calling `convert` with.

Comment: @ZevAverbach the code provided is everything i wrote. Regarding the input file, it's just a usual CrystalReports file, but when I read it and print to the console its just bytes

Comment: @ZevAverbach it's there for me, try to scroll down the code section down, for me it's scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Crystal's .rpt file is a proprietary file format and you are not supposed to be able to read it. Instead, use the Crystal runtime to run the report and export it to CSV.

The latest Crystal runtime uses .NET (Crystal Reports for Visual Studio). Since you are using Python, consider delegating that step to a 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewer or automation tool. Some of these utilities have a full command line API that would allow your Python code to specify the rpt, the login info, parameter values, export format, export file name, etc.

Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party Crystal Reports utilities [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).